# Android app not working in few mobiles

Tags: android, android-studio, mobile-application

Recently I designed an app name "Country Wagon" and its in play store already these are my sdk setting's

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxxxxxxxxxxx.countrywagon"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

but sadly its not supporting for mobiles like ***samsung s3 neo***, ***HTC700*** and these mobiles has the screen size below 5-inches.would that be a problem??. And the app is working pefectly fine for all the mobiles having display above 5inch

Comment: It could be an issue with your minimum SDK, if the current OS version of the devices you mention are too low then the app will not work on those devices, you could try reducing the min SDK to say 16, and see if they work then

Answer (score 1):

You need to change min sdk to 15 in your gradle file

> minSdkVersion 15